# Why my database connection is no valid suddenly in JBoss?

Tags: java, oracle11g, connection-pooling, jboss-eap-7

I have a web application running on **JBoss EAP 7.0.**

Jboss has a configured datasource to **Oracle 11g**.The problem is that after a days web application does not respond any more.

I've checked my log and I can see errors related to database connection:

```
2019-02-05 13:00:02,669 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 21278) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("test-connection-in-pool") failed- direction: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "XXX")
]) - ... "WFLYJCA0040: Failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0047: Connection is not valid"
```

Jboss only responde after a restart. What could have caused this behavior?

Comment: It could be a lot of different reasons. Check this article: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/275036 If still could not find a reason provide more logs.

Comment: This is a generic issue,the root cause you could find in further stack trace of this error.Is this failing for a specific scenario?Could you provide complete stack trace for our analysis?

Comment: No more info, stacktrace only report error, the article shared by @MichałZiober says correctly JBoss only report connection problem, it seems to be a network/traffifc/firewall problem. Now I'm looking for infrastructure problems, thanks.